# SQL Error - Unknown column 'd.courseTitle' in 'field list'

Tags: sql

The sql code is:

```
CREATE VIEW register as select
a.delRef, a.delName, b.eventRef, c.venueRef, c.eventDate,
c.courseRef,d.venueRef, d.courseTitle
from delegate a
inner join booking b
on a.delRef =b.delRef

inner join event c
on b.eventRef = c.eventRef

inner join venue d
on c.venueRef = d.venueRef

where presenter=0;
```

I keep getting the error `Unknown column 'd.courseTitle' in 'field list'`

Please advise, Many thanks

Comment: Do you have `courseTitle` column in `venue` table

Comment: The error is compaling, that inside table `venue` there is no column `courseTitle`. Can you maybe add your table definitions?

Comment: no its in the event table and course table

Comment: If it's in the `event` table and `course` table then don't put `d.courseTitle`. `d` is your `venue` table.

Comment: Then change `d.courseTitle`  to `c.courseTitle` in `select`

Comment: new code CREATE VIEW register as select
a.delRef, a.delName, b.eventRef, c.venueRef, c.eventDate, c.courseRef, d.courseTitle

from delegate a
inner join booking b
on a.delRef =b.delRef

inner join event c
on b.eventRef = c.eventRef

inner join course
on c.courseRef = d.courseRef
where presenter=0;

Comment: Thank you, i have fixed it with your comment :) Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the 'New Code' comment above, I see a d.courseTitle in the SELECT clause, but no JOIN on a table aliased as d.

> inner join course on c.courseRef = d.courseRef

by any chance should this be 'inner join course d on...'  ?